# Firebase Cloud Functions - Cannot Deploy Project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to deploy my Firebase Cloud Functions to my project. I ran, from the command line:

```
firebase deploy
```

I then received the below error; I do not know how to associate with my Firebase project. I ran

```
firebase login
```

as well, and can confirm I am indeed logged in.

[image]

Comment: did you try the commands in the error?

Comment: I can add my project name to it, however unsure of the syntax

Comment: What directory did you cd to?  Does it contain .firebaserc and firebase.json?

Comment: I am currently in the terminal within Android studio, so the root directory of my android project

Comment: Did you ran 'firebase init functions' command?

Comment: The command is literally `firebase use -add`. That will ask you for a name (I typically say `default`) and then show you a list of the Firebase projects associated with your account.

Comment: Thanks, I had to run init and select the project again. I was previously deploying with no issues and wasn't sure what commands I had to run again. Every time I re-open Android Studio I realize I will have to run init. I am not sure if it is best practice to run the cloud functions within Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run...

```
firebase init
```

And follow the steps.